# Calibrating a home gas oven

Tags: equipment, oven

We have a new gas oven which is consistently 30-40F low compared to the dial setting (we've checked with two oven thermometers).  While we can get it calibrated as a service call by the manufacturer, I'd love to know how to do it myself.  However, sources I've been able to search out via Google so far have been uninstructive and somewhat untrustworthy (e.g. eHow.com).

The range is a Summit TNM63027BFKWY 24" gas range.

Questions:

1. Has anyone on SA calibrated their own gas oven?
2. Is gas oven calibration generally the same for most gas ovens in the USA, or does the method vary widely by manufacturer?
3. If (1) is yes, and (2) is "mostly consistent", then can someone point me to a good resource on calibrating your own oven, or failing that, describe the steps?

Comment: Have you checked the thermometers from multiple locations in the oven or just one?

Comment: That's the temperature from the center of my oven, which is the temperature I care about.  If it's hotter around the edges, that doesn't help me much.

Comment: Based on the catastrophic potential of fiddling with your gas line, this question is not suited to Cooking, but would make a better fit on [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @FuzzyChef while we accept such questions as ontopic on Cooking, a SE team member noted that it might get better quality answers on the DIY site. Do you want us to migrate the question, or to keep it here, seeing that you accepted an answer already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need an accurate thermometer that measures *average* temperature to adjust an oven. For example, a [Proaccurate Oven Thermometer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000W4MZ2), which works by having an oil-filled chamber to average the temperature.

Normally, you can just pull the temperature dial off—the (usually) plastic piece you turn generally pulls right off the actual thermostat, its held on by friction. A gentle prying may be necessary.

After removing the knob, you'll have one of two types of adjustments:

1. They'll be two screws on the knob itself (in which case, loosen them both to adjust the temperature, it should be marked as to how much to turn it and in which direction—though, if you stare at it long enough, you can figure it out even if its not marked)
2. There will be one screw inside the shaft on the thermostat. It may be hard to see the screw (it can be at the very end of the hollow shaft). Turn it using a very small screwdriver.

After adjusting the dial, you should re-measure using the thermometer (and possibly adjust again...)

[Appliance411](http://www.appliance411.com/faq/temperature-calibration.shtml) has pictures.

Comment: Thanks, Derobert!  That's a better page link for stoves in general.  HOWEVER, I do need to mention that, having had the repairman here today, Summit stoves have a unique calibration system which is not described by the Appliances411 page.

Answer (score 1):

Having calibrated several ovens myself, I see there is an answer above that details the knob's screwdriver calibration procedure very well, but they left out the part about finding the correct temperature.  To do that, you place two thermometers inside your oven (in case one is slightly off) set the oven to an arbitrary degree point, say, 350-degrees.  You let it run until the main burner shuts off.  At that point, the oven's thermostat has been satisfied and has cut off the gas supply to the main burner.  Then, look to see what temperature the two thermometers are reading and set your oven's control knob to that number.  Now that the control knob is calibrated to the same temperature as the two thermometers inside, it will bake accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I realize it's not exactly what you're asking for, but if it's a consistent offset, I'd simply create a little table and post it near the oven:

```
Desired Temperature   |  Dial Setting
                      |
        100           |       70
        200           |      170
        300           |      270
        400           |      370
        etc.
```

Comment: This is not "how to calibrate"an oven, this is how to put up with one that needs calibrated.